# Out of Memory on Tomcat Shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, wicket

Short description of my problem: I start up Tomcat with my deployed Wicket application. When I want to shut down tomcat I get this error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
at java.lang.ref.Reference.<clinit>(Reference.java:145)
```

I am running the following setup:

- Ubuntu Linux: 10.04 (lucid) with a  2.6.18-028stab094.3 kernel
- Java Version: "1.6.0_26" Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
- Tomcat Version: 7.0.23
- jvm_args:  -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=205m  (these are added via CATALINA_OPTS, nothing else)
- Wicket 1.5.1
- Tomcat is configured with two virtual hosts on subdomains with ModProxy
- My application is deployed as ROOT.war in the appbase directory (it makes no difference if I deploy one or both applications)
- '''No application deployed does not result in OOM on shutdown''', unless I mess around with the jvm args
- The size of the war is about 500k, all libraries are deployed in tomcat/common/lib (directory which I added to common.loader in conf/catalina.properties)
- ulimit -u -> unlimited

When I check the Tomcat manager app it says the following about the JVM memory:

```
Free memory: 470.70 MB Total memory: 490.68 MB Max memory: 490.68 MB
(http connector) Max threads: 200 Current thread count: 6 Current thread busy: 1
```

'top' or 'free -m' is similar:

```
Mem:   2097152k total,  1326772k used,   770380k free,        0k buffers
20029 myuser   18   0  805m 240m  11m S    0 11.7   0:19.24 java
```

I tried to start jmap to get a dump of the heap, it also fails with an OutOfMemoryError. Actually as long as one or both of my applications are deployed any other java process fails with the same OOM Error (see top).

The problem occurs while the application is deployed. So something is seriously wrong with it. However the application is actually running smoothly for quite a while. But I have seen OOMs in the application as well, so I don't trust the calm.

My application is using a custom filter class? Could that be it?

For completeness (hopefully), here's the list of libraries in my common/lib:

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
antlr-runtime-3.3.jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-commons-3.1.jar
asm-tree-3.1.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-email-1.2.jar
dependencies-provided.tgz
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-jaspic_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar
hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-search-3.1.0.GA.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
joda-time-1.6.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
lombok-0.9.3.jar
lucene-core-2.4.0.jar
mail-1.4.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.14.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
quartz-2.1.1.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
stringtemplate-4.0.2.jar
wicket-auth-roles-1.5.1.jar
wicket-core-1.5.1.jar
wicket-datetime-1.5.1.jar
wicket-extensions-1.5.1.jar
wicket-request-1.5.1.jar
wicket-util-1.5.1.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

I appreciate any hint or even speculation that gives me additional ideas what to try.

*Update*: I tested some more and found that this behaviour only occurs while one or both of my applications are deployed. The behaviour does not occur on "empty" tomcat (that was a mistake on my part messing with jvm args)

*Update2*: I am currently experimenting trying to reproduce this behaviour in a virtual box, I want to debug this with a profiler. I am still not convinved that it should be impossible to run my setup on 2GB RAM.

*Update3* (10/01/12): I am trying to run jenkins instead of my own application. Same behaviour, so it is definitely server configuration issues. Jenkins jobs fail when maven is called, so I need not even try the shutdown hack suggested below because I need a second java process while running Jenkins. It was suggested to me that because this is a Virtual Server ulimits may be imposed from outside and I would not be able to see them. I think I'll ask a new question regarding this. Thx all.

*Update4* (02/05/12): see below for the answer that contains the hint. I'll clarify some more up here: I am now 95% sure that the errors occur because I am reaching my thread limit. However because this is a virtual server the method described below would not work to check this value because it is not visible with ulimit, that was what was confusing me and only today I found out that this is the "numproc" value that I can see in the Parallels Power Panel that I can log into for my virtual server. There were Resource Alerts for numproc but I did not see those either until just now. The value has a hard limit of 96 which I cannot change of course. The current value of numproc corresponds to the number of processes I see with "top" after toggling "H" to see threads. I had a very hard time finding this because this numproc value is hidden deep inside the panel. Sadly 96 is a rather low number if you want to run a tomcat with apache and mysql. I am also very sad that I cannot even find this value in the small print of my hosting contract and it is rather relevant to my application I dare say. So I guess I'll need a server upgrade.

Thanks all for your helpful answers in the end everyone helped me a bit to find out what the problem was.

Comment: What happens if you run `free -m` in the terminal while tomcat is running?

Comment: Also, do you have any special catalina_opts?

Comment: jetty-all-server seems weird for me. All other dependencies seems fine, but why embed jetty in Tomcat (maybe needed by Wicket, I don't know Wicket).

Comment: ah thanks for the hint with jetty that must be from testing. I should remove that.

Comment: Perhaps you can get a heap dump with the -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option to the JVM: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: no that doesn't work either, thx though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have too many threads open.

Use this command :

```
ulimit -u
```

What is the result ?
Should be something like :

```
max user processes (-u) 100
```

If this is correct, you can edit this file :

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

and the the following modifications :

```
#<domain> <type> <item> <value>
user soft nproc 10000
user hard nproc 10000
```

Comment: thanks for that. ulimit -u gives me the information that user processes are unlimited

Comment: Maybe another hint : add -Xss128k

Comment: I never stop learning. But sadly this did not provide the solution. Tomcat Manager tells me there are very few threads running anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I finally found your answer to be the correct one. It is not quite perfect because ulimit -u does not tell me this. I had to go into the parallels panel to find out that my thread limit is 96 and I was using that up pretty fast with tomcat, apache, mysql ...

Answer (score 4):

The tomcat shutdown procedure consits of sending an command/word via a tcp port to the running tomcat VM. This port is configured in the server.xml (if I remember corretly, writting on my phone right now). So far so good.

Unfortunately, the shutdown script does this by starting a 2. VM using the same java options used for the tomcat. Your system simply has not enough memory for this.

As a sollution you could write your own stop script using telnet or something.

I could help with later if needed.

Hope that helps.
Viele grüsse Bert

Comment: The idea is good, what I don't get is that it seens impossible to start two java processes on 2GB of RAM. Not even my Eclipse - java-based last thing I remember - needs 1GB or so my System Monitor tells me.

Comment: If your Eclipse is not needing 2GB you are doing it wrong ;)
In honest: you only give the XmX and PermGen options? They sum up to ~800MB you see in the top output. Not sure about the memory reported by the tomcat manager. They don 't align with the output of top. But in the end, the problems is as descibed above; tomcat uses the same options for the run configurations as for the stop script.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably survive for a while like this. All you need to do is kill the tomcat process whenever you need to restart it. It is not a nice approach, but the main concern is that your application runs correctly.

It seems to me though, that on the long run, you might need to order a hosting plan with more RAM available.

Comment: I am trying to check if this might indeed be it - despite the system seemingly telling me there is enough RAM. So I am trying to run the setup on my development machine but the setup takes some time to reproduce here.

Comment: I was in a similar situation with a Struts2 & GWT application a few months ago, and had to kill Tomcat for about three weeks whenever i needed to stop the server, which was not very often. Fortunately the application run well.

Comment: Every once in a while the application crashes as well. It's quite a small application, too. I cannot seem to get the real numbers of memory consumption. All numbers I have say "it's fine" but the exceptions say it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with a tomcat installation just last week. I managed to fix it by giving tomcat a smaller heap.  Something like this:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=”-Xms256m -Xmx512m”
```

Before starting Tomcat may help.  In the meantime you'll have to kill it the old fashioned way, with a `kill -9` ;)

EDIT: you could also take look [here](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/eclipse/reducing-tomcats-thread-count.jspx), it appears tomcat automatically creates a bunch of "spare" threads, but you can limit those as well as your max thread count in the config. Hope it helps.

Comment: Interestingly the behaviour is a bit different now. I'll experiment some more with that.

Comment: Glad to help if it did, take a look at the edit I just posted, might be your problem is the default "spare" thread count.

Comment: That link is good. Did not provide the solution to this specific problem, but nevertheless a good reminder of possible future issues.